# How to send other data than title and body in Firebase Messaging Service? (Node.js, Android)

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on an Android app and by using Node.js based function, I'm sending notification to Android and in Android onMessageReceived() function is used to receive data to show notifications. Now the problem, I'm facing is that I want to send some String type data in parallel to Title and Body. What changes should I make?
Here is my Node.js code

```
'use-strict'
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document("Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}").onWrite((change,context)=> {
const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;
console.log("User ID:"+user_id+" | Notification ID:"+notification_id);
return admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user_id).collection("Notifications").doc(notification_id).get().then(queryResult =>{
    const from_user_id = queryResult.data().from;
    const from_message = queryResult.data().Message;
    const from_data = admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(from_user_id).get();
    const to_data = admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user_id).get();
    return Promise.all([from_data,to_data]).then(result =>{
        const from_name = result[0].data().Name;
        const to_name = result[1].data().Name;
        const token_id = result[1].data().Token_ID;
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: "Hey! "+from_name+" here",
                body: "Dear "+to_name+", "+from_message+", Will you help me?",
                icon: "default"
            }
        };
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id,payload).then(result =>{
            return console.log("Notification Sent.");
        });
    });
});
});
```

And Here is my android code:

```
public class FirebaseMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    String messageTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String messageBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.enough);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
            .setSound(sound)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(messageBody))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    int mNotificationID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(mNotificationID,mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While I know squad about nodejs (or js in general) I got this working yesterday by passing a `data` object in the payload.

So, the json request that google makes (I'm using GCM still, but I'm sure FCM would be the same, or very similar payload) looks like this:

```
{
  "to": "<GCM/FCM token>",
  "priority": "normal",
  "android_channel_id": -99,
  "data": {
    "title": "Some title",
    "body": "Some body",
    "more_data_one": "Some more data",
    "more_data_two": "Some more data, again!"
  }
}
```

Somehow, however, if I send both `data` and `notification` in the payload, the `GCMServiceListener` never gets called, and the app just displays whatever is in the `notification` portion of the payload.

By adding the `data` section (and therefore making the notification a "silent" notification), you are then on charge of intercepting the message, and displaying it with the Notification builder.

Comment: Just one minor edit, the `data` message contents are only handled strictly by `onMessageReceived()` if and only if its the only message type in the payload. If it still has the `notification` message, the usual behavior is that when the app is in background, the Android system will handle the notification by showing the `notification` contents, and the `data` contents can be retrieved from the intent of the opened activity. See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notification-messages-with-optional-data-payload) for more details. Cheers!